# Restricting the area where divs can be moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This [link](http://jsfiddle.net/puf6s47r/) reflects live preview of my code.

### HTML

```
<h1>Detect overlapping with JavaScript</h1>



<div id="area">
  <div id="box0"></div>
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
  <div id="box4">4</div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

### Javascript

```
var overlaps = (function() {
  function getPositions(elem) {
    var pos, width, height;
    pos = $(elem).position();
    width = $(elem).width();
    height = $(elem).height();
    return [
      [pos.left, pos.left + width],
      [pos.top, pos.top + height]
    ];
  }

  function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
    var r1, r2;
    r1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
    r2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
    return r1[1] > r2[0] || r1[0] === r2[0];
  }

  return function(a, b) {
    var pos1 = getPositions(a),
      pos2 = getPositions(b);
    return comparePositions(pos1[0], pos2[0]) && comparePositions(pos1[1], pos2[1]);
  };
})();

function m() {
  var area = $('#area')[0],
    box = $('#box0')[0],
    html;

  html = $(area).children().not(box).map(function(i) {

    if (overlaps(box, this)) {

      $("#box" + (i + 1)).removeClass('remTouch').addClass("touch");


    }
    return '<p>Red box + Box ' + (i + 1) + ' = ' + overlaps(box, this) + '</p>';


  }).get().join('');

  $('#result').html(html);


}

$('#box0').draggable({
  drag: function() {
    $(".touch").removeClass("touch").addClass('remTouch');
    m();
  }
});
```

I have divs in this code one of which is draggable. It pushes the div to which it is collided. The problem is that i want to bring such a functionality in it that when it is collided from upper side it moves to lower side and similarly when from left side it will move in the right direction but will not cross the border of its container div.

Comment: You mean to say red div should push and move the number divs ?

Comment: if you have experienced UC browser and noticed those bubbles in there at homepage, i want to make it just like that

Comment: i meant to say that when red div collides with another div so that one will be pushed forward and when collision is false the affected div will come back to its position

Comment: I think you should implement using jQuery UI sortable

Comment: Restricting movement inside the div could be done through the `containment` option of the jQuery UI draggable. you just need to add `containment: "#area"` to the draggable's options object. - Check: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

Comment: yes but i want the pushed div to not get out of the container